# Python. Flask server is not working in pydroid app(android) with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, flask, multiprocessing, pydroid

Написал приложение на *PyQt5*. 
Создал вкладку с запуском сервера, который может работать в локальной сети. 
Создал функцию, в которую поместил `app.run()`. 
Запускаю это функцию через `multiprocessing` (`threading` тоже пробовал). 
По нажатию кнопки "**`старт`**", сервер запускается, функция вызывается, но после запуска сервер сразу фризится и на него не проходят ни какие запросы. 
Причем на пк этот же код работает.

**P.S.** пробовал запускать чисто *flask* он не работает при свернутом окне *pydroid*.

**P.S.2.** выключил в настройках оптимизацию *pydroid*, *flask* заработал даже со свернутым *pydroid*, но он по прежнему не работает с *PyQt5*. Может кто знает как решить?

**P.S.3** вот код, это не код моего приложения, а его упрощенная модель и она также не работает. 
При запуске и после завершения в консоли: "**`Start`**" и "**`End`**",  код вообще не запускался. Или есть какой-то другой метод запуска?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from flask import Flask
import sys
import logging
import multiprocessing


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self, text="start")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.show()
        
    def start(self):
        server = multiprocessing.Process(target=app_run)
        server.start()
        self.btn.setDisabled(True)

app = Flask(__name__)       
def app_run():
    try:
        handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        handler.setLevel(0)
        app.logger.addHandler(handler)
        print("Start")
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, debug=False)
    except AttributeError:
        print("End")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    win = MyWindow()
    qapp.exec()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65597622/cant-display-pyqt5-gui-with-threading-flaskapi/65602935#65602935 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64681709/pyqt-with-flask-dont-show-the-mainwindow/64695355#64695355 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422975/how-to-move-out-of-app-run-in-flask-api-python , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634845/running-server-in-background-while-app-does-something-else , ...

Comment: Всё это не то, в них описываются проблеммы, которые у меня либо не возникли, либо они уже решены.